# Converting type on column crashes the kernel with no error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I am trying to convert a string type column to numeric in Jupyter notebook (python3).

```
df['x'] = df.x.astype('float64')
```

When I run above cell, the `kernel` crashes with raising no error.

My rough guess is that the cause for this situation is that there is a value that cannot be converted to `float64`. A corrupted value somewhere along the way!

I am not sure how to search for that corrupted value though, since the size is as big as 19 Million string types values e.g. `123.0023`. They have too many categories and that makes it difficult to search. Thoughts?

Comment: Try `pd.to_numeric(df['x'], errors='coerce')`. This will make ill-formatted values to `NaN`

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks for the comment. I just tried that. The same thing happens again.

Comment: @Ch3steR I tried this for the second time. The kernel is not dead yet, but it is taking a really long time! not sure what's happening...

Comment: My best guess would be since the df is large there might be `MemoryError`. Again not sure tho.

Comment: I wish it gives me an error message :(

Comment: just another observation. The conversation for another column in the same way finishes successfully in a relatively short time